# WrapDateLine of Bing maps in Openlayers

Tags: gis, bing-maps, openlayers

I am using openlayers' bing maps as base layers in my map. However, when zoom out to the max extent of the map,  I cann't pan east or west any more even I set the wrapDateLine to true.  I changed the base layer to yahoo! or google maps everything works fine.  Any one countered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Depending your implementation, it might not be supported in OpenLayers as described in the documentation for the Bing Maps layer. There is no option called wrapDateLine contrary to Google Maps layer, see for comparison:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Bing-js.html

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html

Share your code or put it on jsfiddle so we could try to help you further.